# AddUserCollectionToGroup Web Service

Tags: web-services

I'm using MOSS 2007. Does anyone know if there is a limit to the number of user names that can be passed to the AddUserCollectionToGroup web service? I have around 300 and was wondering if I should break that into multiple calls and if so, how many? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific limit to the AddUserCollectionToGroup webservice. So we can add n number of users to SharePoint Group by using this service. But if the users increased in Group, will affect the performance. For 300 users, we can add to the Group by using this service without any issue.

Comment: On ShPt 2010 I get `<faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The request is too large. We only accept 100 items at once.</errorstring>`

Answer (score 1):

I have verified adding 750-800 users at a time and face no problem and it shouldn't be a problem as well. You can also see the [complete WSDL here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd965659%28v=office.12%29.aspx)